# Manual key not showing up on hat leaderboard

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

Users with the secret "Manual Key" hat are not showing up with the hat on the leaderboards. (In effect, this makes the leaderboards look incorrect. (See below)

[image: Yaakov without manual key]
In this image, Yaakov is pictured with all his hats *but* his Manual Key.

[image: Wolgwang]
The Manual Key hat does not show up here for Wolgwang either. (And for some reason, Double-beep's total is wrong, but I won't ask about that...)

**Update:**
Seems like the problem is no longer an issue - Leaderboards just got updated. (see here) https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network

Comment: Hat it manual not automated :P

Comment: That could explain why it's not in the leaderboard code... It still seems odd though.

Comment: It is visible right now, no?

Comment: Yes. It is no longer visible (hence the edit)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Comp Sci, two hard things:
> cache invalidation, names,
> off-by-one errors